# TCP Listener between a Windows and Linux in c# using MONO

Tags: c#, mono

I have a problem when comunicating between a TCP-SERVER witch is located on Windows opened on ip `1.1.1.1` and a TCP-CLIENT on Linux opened with MONO on `2.2.2.2`.

The problem is that from the same machine works, but remote won't work. I tried deactivating firewall on WINDOWS, nothing.

**SERVER :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TcpServerTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting server ...");

            if(args.Length == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Custom params {0} {1}", args[0], args[1]);

                Server srv1 = new Server(args[0].ToString(),Int32.Parse(args[1]));
                srv1.createListener();
            }
            else
            {
                Server srv1 = new Server();
                srv1.createListener();
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Server
    {
        static string output = "";

        string defaultIP = "localhost";
        int defaultPort = 4500;

        IPAddress ipAddress = null;

        public Server()
        {
            this.ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry("ff90::742b:418c:ee82:3cca%12").AddressList[0];
        }

        public Server(string ip, int port)
        {
            // this.ipAddress = Dns.GetHostEntry(ip).AddressList[0];
            this.ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ip);

            this.defaultIP = ip;
            this.defaultPort = port;
        }

        public void createListener()
        {
            // Create an instance of the TcpListener class.
            TcpListener tcpListener = null;

            Console.WriteLine(ipAddress);
            try
            {
                // Set the listener on the local IP address 
                // and specify the port.
                tcpListener = new TcpListener(ipAddress, defaultPort);
                tcpListener.Start();
                output = "Waiting for a connection...";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                output = "Error: " + e.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
            while (true)
            {
                // Always use a Sleep call in a while(true) loop 
                // to avoid locking up your CPU.
                Thread.Sleep(10);
                // Create a TCP socket. 
                // If you ran this server on the desktop, you could use 
                // Socket socket = tcpListener.AcceptSocket() 
                // for greater flexibility.
                TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
                // Read the data stream from the client. 
                byte[] bytes = new byte[256];
                NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
                stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                SocketHelper helper = new SocketHelper();
                helper.processMsg(tcpClient, stream, bytes);
            }
        }
    }

    class SocketHelper
    {
        TcpClient mscClient;
        string mstrMessage;
        string mstrResponse;
        byte[] bytesSent;
        public void processMsg(TcpClient client, NetworkStream stream, byte[] bytesReceived)
        {
            // Handle the message received and  
            // send a response back to the client.
            mstrMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytesReceived.Length);
            mscClient = client;
            mstrMessage = mstrMessage.Substring(0, 5);

            IPEndPoint remoteIpEndPoint = client.Client.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint;
            IPEndPoint localIpEndPoint = client.Client.LocalEndPoint as IPEndPoint;

            if (mstrMessage.Equals("Hello"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved Hello from "+ remoteIpEndPoint.Address+":"+ remoteIpEndPoint.Port);
                mstrResponse = "Goodbye";
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved Hello from " + remoteIpEndPoint.Address + ":" + remoteIpEndPoint.Port);
                Console.WriteLine("Recieved error ...");
                mstrResponse = "What?";
            }
            bytesSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(mstrResponse);
            stream.Write(bytesSent, 0, bytesSent.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

**CLIENT :**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TcpClientTest1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting cllient ..");

            if (args.Length == 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Custom params {0} {1}", args[0], args[1]);

                Client cln1 = new Client(args[0].ToString(), Int32.Parse(args[1]));
                cln1.Connect(args[0].ToString(), "Hello");
            }
            else
            {
                Client cln1 = new Client();
                cln1.Connect("ab54::742b:418c:ee82:3cca%12", "Hello");
            }

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Client
    {
        string defaultIP = "localhost";
        int defaultPort = 4500;

        public Client()
        {

        }

        public Client(string ip, int port)
        {
            this.defaultIP = ip;
            this.defaultPort = port;
        }

        public void Connect(string serverIP, string message)
        {
            string output = "";

            try
            {
                // Create a TcpClient. 
                // The client requires a TcpServer that is connected 
                // to the same address specified by the server and port 
                // combination.
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(defaultIP, defaultPort);

                // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a byte array.
                Byte[] data = new Byte[256];
                data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);

                // Get a client stream for reading and writing. 
                // Stream stream = client.GetStream();
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                output = "Sent: " + message;
                Console.WriteLine(output);

                // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                data = new Byte[256];

                // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                String responseData = String.Empty;

                // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                output = "Received: " + responseData;
                Console.WriteLine(output);

                // Close everything.
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                output = "ArgumentNullException: " + e;
                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                output = "SocketException: " + e.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

SERVER NORMAL OUTPUT (windows same machine) :

```
>>TcpServerTest1.exe 2.2.2.2 4500
Starting server ...
Custom params 2.2.2.2 4500
2.2.2.2
Recieved Hello from 2.2.2.2:55442
```

CLIENT NORMAL OUTPUT (windows same machine):

```
>>TcpClientTest1.exe "2.2.2.2" "4500"
Starting cllient ..
Custom params 2.2.2.2 4500
Sent: Hello
Received: Goodbye
```

SERVER NORMAL OUTPUT (windows):

```
>>TcpServerTest1.exe 2.2.2.2 4500
Starting server ...
```

CLIENT NORMAL OUTPUT (linux):

```
root@server1:/home/monotest# mono TcpClientTest1.exe 2.2.2.2 4500
Starting cllient ..
Custom params 2.2.2.2 4500
SocketException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Connection timed out
  at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect (System.Net.EndPoint remoteEP) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEP) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
  at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect (System.Net.IPAddress[] ipAddresses, Int32 port) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

SERVER NORMAL OUTPUT (linux same machine):

```
root@server1:/home/monotest# mono TcpClientTest1.exe 2.2.2.2 4500
Starting cllient ..
Custom params 2.2.2.2 4500
Sent: Hello
Received: Goodbye
```

CLIENT NORMAL OUTPUT (linux same machine):

```
root@server1:/home/monotest# mono TcpServerTest1.exe 2.2.2.2 4500
Starting server ...
Custom params 2.2.2.2 4500
2.2.2.2
```

Basically same machine works, but not remote.

Before this i had a problem because windows was forcing to open TCP Client on ipv6 and i saw printing `Starting server on ff90::742b:418c:ee82:3cca%12 ...`, but i managed to solve it, now i have this problem.

What it can be? It is clearly not a firewall problem.

Comment: IP addresses 1.1.1.1 and 2.2.2.2 are not within the IP address of the windows machine.  The IP address to be accessible from other machine have to be within the subnet of the IP address and mask of the windows IP address for the PC.  Start by using from cmd.exde the IP address and mask of your PC : netstat /all

Comment: Find a computer network book and you should check what the other comment means there.