# HTTPS traffic not captured using FiddlerCore on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, proxy, .net-core, fiddlercore

Trying to capture all traffic from browser using FiddlerCore using the .NetStandard libraries.
Below is what I have:

```
 public class ProxyConfig
        {
            private const string SecureEndpointHostname = "localhost";
            private readonly int _secureEndpointPort = 18888;

            private static readonly ICollection<Session> AllSessions = new List<Session>();

            private static Fiddler.Proxy _secureEndpoint;

            private static readonly LoggerCnx Logger = new LoggerCnx();

            public void SetupProxyListener()
            {
                // This is a workaround for known issue in .NET Core - https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/issues/12668
                CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

                FiddlerApplication.BeforeRequest += session =>
                {
                    // In order to enable response tampering, buffering mode MUST
                    // be enabled; this allows FiddlerCore to permit modification of
                    // the response in the BeforeResponse handler rather than streaming
                    // the response to the client as the response comes in.
                    session.bBufferResponse = false;
                    lock (AllSessions)
                    {
                        AllSessions.Add(session);
                    }
                };

                Logger.Info($"Starting {FiddlerApplication.GetVersionString()}...");
                CONFIG.IgnoreServerCertErrors = true;
                CONFIG.bCaptureCONNECT = true;

                FiddlerApplication.Prefs.SetBoolPref("fiddler.network.streaming.abortifclientaborts", true);

                FiddlerCoreStartupFlags startupFlags = FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.Default;
                startupFlags = (startupFlags | FiddlerCoreStartupFlags.DecryptSSL);

                FiddlerApplication.Startup(BaseConfiguration.ProxyPort, startupFlags);

                Logger.Info("Created endpoint listening on port {0}", BaseConfiguration.ProxyPort);

                Logger.Info("Starting with settings: [{0}]", startupFlags);
                Logger.Info("Gateway: {0}", CONFIG.UpstreamGateway.ToString());

                // Create a HTTPS listener, useful for when FiddlerCore is masquerading as a HTTPS server
                // instead of acting as a normal CERN-style proxy server.
                _secureEndpoint = FiddlerApplication.CreateProxyEndpoint(_secureEndpointPort, true, SecureEndpointHostname);
                if (null != _secureEndpoint)
                {
                    Logger.Info("Created secure endpoint listening on port {0}, using a HTTPS certificate for '{1}'", _secureEndpointPort, SecureEndpointHostname);
                }
            }
}
```

Everything seems to work fine on Windows, all traffic is captured, HTTP and HTTPS.

The problem arises when I'm trying to do the same when running the code on Linux (tried it on both VM and Linux conainer, Ubuntu 16.04). HTTP traffic is captured but HTTPS is not.

Any idea what I'm I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like you do not need to connect.  See : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/498b0307-3dfc-4b19-8ac2-38f10ee87515/udp-socket-communication-between-a-linux-server-and-a-window-client-machine-in-c?forum=netfxnetcom

Comment: I tried to set `CONFIG.bCaptureCONNECT = false;` (just in case it's true by default) but I'm still not seeing the HTTPS traffic...

Comment: I don't think you are getting errors.  So I suspect the "localhost" is set up wrong.  the Linux IP and the Windows PC are usually different.  The local host on Windows is setup in the file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. In Windows I usually recommend listening to Address.IPAny.  You have to be careful if you are using IPV4 or IPV6 since the settings are different.

Comment: Good, valid point for localhost. Thank you for that. However, it seems it still doesn't fix my issue even though I'm using `IPAddress.Any`

Comment: It looks like the listening port in Linux is different from windows but the linux must be within the mask of the Windows IP address.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040307/tcp-listener-between-a-windows-and-linux-in-c-sharp-using-mono

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't get exactly what you mean. Could you please try to give a bit more details?

Comment: The IP address for Linux and Windows are different.  So if windows IP is 172.10.10.5 with mask 255.255.255.0.  then Linux IP address can be anything from 172.10.10.1 to 172.10.10.254.

Comment: I think I get what you're saying, but (if I got it right) I don't need the proxy to capture traffic from one OS to the other but within the same OS. For example, I need this to capture traffic from browsers running on the same OS, with Selenium tests. The browsers choice is quite large, like all for Windows, and the same for Mac. Besides this, in CI it's way faster to provision a Linux VM or container than a Windows one. Does this make sense?

Comment: Proxy has nothing to do with the capturing of the traffic.  Only the tool for de-crypting the captured data.  The data is http packets and the browser shouldn't make a lot if difference since you are only looking at the text messages (not displaying the graphics).  Linux is more efficient than windows so capturing on Linux make sense.